# Are these sets linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be a basis for a real vector space $X$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. I'm trying to prove, using the basis, that every subset of $X$ with cardinality greater than n is linearly dependent. Could you give me some hints?

N/A: I tried to write the elements of the set as a linear combination, and combine them. But I didn't get somewhere.

Comment: The definition of a basis is that you can write any vector in terms of the vectors of the basis.  Including the rest of your vectors.

Comment: This has been asked at least a hundred times on this site. Have you looked for duplicates?